# How was the East German local bureaucracy consolidated after unification?

Tags: german-unification

Related: [How did Germany deal with the East German communist Government structure after unification?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/39300/how-did-germany-deal-with-the-east-german-communist-government-structure-after-u)

The question I linked above has a great answer for the general picture, but I am more interested in tracking down how the process went in individual jurisdictions. This includes me finding references for questions like:

- When senior officials got forced into retirement, how were their replacements picked?
- For jurisdictions where established officials were left in charge, what was the reasoning to do so? How were they kept under check?
- How were oligarch takeovers prevented, in case any ousted officials tried to organize as mobs like in St. Petersburg after the Soviet collapse?

To clarify after a comment, I am not trying to answer those under this post so much as trying to find help on accessing references on transitions in local jurisdictions

Comment: You should stick to a single question per thread and try to keep things focused. Adding sub-questions can make answers lengthy and difficult to follow.

Comment: My bad, I am not trying to get replies for those sub-questions so much as trying to clarify the main question. I will edit to make that clear

Comment: A portion of your question is answered here: [Neue Länder – Wikipedia - Neuaufbau der Länder- und Kommunalverwaltungen nach 1990](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neue_L%C3%A4nder#Neuaufbau_der_L%C3%A4nder-_und_Kommunalverwaltungen_nach_1990) **Note**: the English version of this page doesn't contain this chapter.

Comment: Here is my recollection, based on a conversation with a scientist from West Germany. In 1990-91, after the reunification, he was sent, as a part of a team, to del with DDR research institutes. He found most institute members utterly useless; they were given pensions and sent to retirement.